# What's difference between Rishi, Rajarishi, Maha Rishi, Brahma Rishi and Saptarishi?

Tags: rishi, terminology

I have heard a lot about those rishis. I know these are categories or may be level/rank of rishis. "Rishis" are bottom level and "Saptarishi" are top level. But what made them any of these? I mean, If one has become Rishi then how he can become Maharishi or Brahma rishi or any other. And what's the difference between them? Any  scriptures describes this concept?

Comment: Is Vishwamitra Brahma Rishi?

Comment: @akshaykumars Yes, Brahma himself declared Vishwamitra as Brahma Rishi. But Vishwamitra requested Brahma that Rish(brhama rishi) vashishta should diclair me Brahma Rishi because he is the reason that I got inspiration to start my Journey of becoming a Brahma Rishi. Later he became one of the Saptarishi also.

Comment: @akshaykumars If you want you can watch whole journey of Parshurama, from arrogant king to Brahma rishi on youtube videos. [Here is the link..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfxrSyrajyQ)

Comment: @Rishabh you meant to say "Vishwamitra"; not "Parshurama" ?

Comment: Vishwamitra is my inspiration too!

Comment: @akshaykumars Oh yes... I mean Vishwamitra. Don't know how I typed Parshurama!!

Comment: @Rishabh no problem. Vishwamitra Rishi is my role model

Comment: Brahm Rishi have powers equivalent to Brahma and can create a whole creation in future with power of Tapas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trishanku Vishwamitra created whole new heaven, and hence we have 2 heavens in this creation and he was not even a Brahmin, no demi god, just a normal king Kaushik